# Woocommerce latest review

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, review

I am trying to get the latest comment / review on any product on my test page, so far i am treating it as a post, and got something like this :

```
<?php
    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product');
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);
?>

<?php get_comments( $args ); ?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$number_of_reviews = 10; //How many reviews you want to retrieve
$reviews = get_comments( array( 'number' => $number_of_reviews, 'status' => 'approve', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product' ) );

echo "<ul>";
foreach ( (array) $reviews as $review ) {
    $_product = WC_get_product( $review->comment_post_ID );
    $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $review->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );

    echo '<li style="list-style:none"><a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link( $review->comment_ID ) ) . '">';
        echo $_product->get_title() . '</a>  ';
        for($i=0;$i<$rating;$i++){
            echo "<span style='color:grey'>&#9733</span>";
        }
        echo "<p>".$review->comment_content."    -   ".get_comment_author($review->comment_ID)."</p>";

    echo '</li><br><br>';
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Note:** You can always modify your code as per your need and CSS as well.

Comment: its cutting off everything from that line and bellow, like an unclosed php tag or something liek that , i tryed to add the php tags on start and end , on 1st and 2nd part still just fizzled the page

Comment: How did you implemented my code and where ? And what is 1st and 2nd part?

Comment: index.php, inside a div, line 1 and 2 starting $ 1st part, the rest 2nd part

Comment: Same code working fine for me. So if you want someone to help you need to post relevant things in your question then and then somebody can help you.

Comment: You can also try by debugging in my code like putting `var_dump($reviews);` to see how many reviews it retrieves. This can be your start point of your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the latest comment for a product:

```
function display_product_review() {
    global $product;

    $comments = get_approved_comments( $product->id );

    $product_link = '/product/' . $product->post->post_name . "/#tab-reviews/";

    if ( !empty ($comments) ) {
        echo $comments[0]->comment_content . '<br><a href="'. $product_link . '">Read more reviews...</a>';
    } else {
        echo "There are no reviews for this product yet. Would you like to <a href='" . $product_link ."'>add your own review</a>?";       
    }
}
```

The only downside is that get_approved_comments only has one parameter, which is the post_id, so it does pull all reviews made for the product. It may not be the cleanest solution, but it did work for me.